# arc diff a branch which already pushed to remote by creating a new branch in git

Tags: git, phabricator

This is a situation where I needed to do.
I have a branch in my local, say testBranch (which contains a modified file `file.txt`).
I've already pushed testBranch to remote by `git push origin testBranch`.
So I cannot arc diff so that other people can review my code via Phabricator (since I already pushed)

What my co-worker did was create a new branch, say testBranch1 as follows:

```
git checkout testBranch
git merge master            // merge master to testBranch

git checkout master
git pull --rebase           // git pull while my local update reserved

git checkout testBranch
git merge master             // merge master to testBranch

git checkout master
git merge testBranch          // merge testBranch to master

git reset origin/master      // set the current HEAD to origin/master in my local
git checkout -b testBranch1
arc diff
```

Now others can review the modified `file.txt` in newBranch1 via Phabraicator. I have no idea what's going on and why this works. Could anyone explain why this works?

Answer (score 5):

Arcanist (`arc`) is a pre-commit (a.k.a. pre-push) code review.  Once the branch is pushed to origin, it has defeated the purpose of Arcanist.  Once you have pushed, you have a few options:

1. Delete the branch on origin with `git push origin --delete testBranch`.
2. When running the `arc diff` command, tell it what you want to base it from like this: `arc diff origin/master`.
3. Do the steps above, however, you should note, there is no git push on the above lines which is what is solving the issue.